# Markdown in outlook

Tags: outlook, markdown

Because this is not the kind of company where wiki's are accepted, we tend to do a lot of communication through outlook. Sending code snippets through it is painfull.
Is there some way to get the markdown thing we have here, but in outlook?

Comment: Sorry, could you be more specific? What kind of behavior would you like to have in Outlook?

Comment: He wants to be able to use markdown (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) syntax in Outlook

Comment: More context on the question at: Markdown vs markup - are they related? 
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041/markdown-vs-markup-are-they-related>

Comment: Can you use thunderbird ? if yes, this might plugin might work: https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here

Comment: This should be marked as the answer to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17409971/73025

Answer (score 48, accepted):

For future visitors: https://github.com/mmanela/MarkdownOutlook

Per their wiki:

> A simple plugin for Outlook 2013 which adds a button to the compose mail menu to enable Markdown mode. When enabled your email will be turned from Markdown syntax to html when sending.
>
> - Uses MarkdownSharp for the markdown conversion
> - Uses VSTO to integrate with Outlook
> - Uses an Installer Project to build an installer

Comment: The project now says for Outlook 2013. :-/

Comment: Are there any build instructions for people that use Outlook but aren't familiar with the C# ecosystem ?

Comment: For visitors from the future! :)

Comment: @DavidMurdoch, it works on my Outlook 2010 anyway

Comment: It seems to work with Outlook 2016 as well, though I haven't tested it too much yet

Comment: Visitors from future here :-) This works with Outlook 2016, but I had a difficult time to adjust the image size if I use image syntax and it's also a pain on inserting a word document as attachment in the middle of the email.

Comment: This works with Outlook 2016, but the code syntax (starts/ends with ```) doesn't seem to work. Some great person worked on this feature/fix, but there is no installation package at the moment :-(

Comment: @JaeyoungChun where did you find the project that had the code fixed?

Answer (score 15):

I haven't been able to find an editor BUT you can write your email where I'm typing now which will show you the result in the preview pane. (including code snippets)

You can then copy the result from the preview pane into outlook (I've tried thunderbird too and it works)

If at first your code doesnt render nicely (ie colour coded) then ensure you are editing in the 'Ask Question' editor (not in the Your Answer section) - this made a difference for me.

Comment: Although not extremely practical, this is the best suggestion so far :) Thanks

Comment: There are live markdown render websites out there.

Comment: nice one! It's really helpful! I use Markdown Viewer++ plugin for notepad++!

Comment: Outlook has problems dealing with some styles though.

Comment: Unfortunately Outlook corrupts numbered lists when pasted. Specifically: It adds numbers to code sections under numbered items.

Comment: I write in emacs markdown mode and @wal's suggestion works best for me. I use `https://stackedit.io/app#` online to then get my rendered text and it seems to work pretty well :)

Answer (score 9):

Since Outlook uses Word as an email editor (Outlook 2007, Outlook 2003 can be configured to use Word) you could use the AutoCorrect feature to apply simple formatting to your email. `__text__` will trigger italic and `**bold**` will trigger bold. List can be created automatically when typing `-` or `1.`

Another option might be to run a VBA macro on sending the email which converts the Markdown formatting to (X)HTML.

Answer (score 5):

I've taken to running [Markdown Pro](http://www.markdownpro.com) on my Mac and pasting the preview pane results into the message. Painful but workable.

There is a similar editor, [MarkdownPad](http://markdownpad.com), for Windows, but I have not tried it.

Comment: Looks promising. Download is blocked by corporate FW however, so it'll have to wait 'till later.

Comment: MarkdownPad works well for Windows. And the solution isn't terribly inconvenient. But, it takes some effort to modify the default CSS to match fonts and sizing in Outlook so that they email *look and feel* flows. That is very nit-picky, but it's a reality if you care.

Comment: I'm here 11 years later still frustrated at outlook for not supporting markdown. But copying the preview pane from MacDown works for me.

Answer (score 5):

If you use [Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/), then you can use the [markdown-here](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here) extension.

Comment: you can added directly in your browser as an extension an **M** icon will be added that enables markdown in your emails .
https://markdown-here.com/get.html

Answer (score 2):

My outlook 2007 works with basic markdown _italic_ and *bold* with no configuration.

Comment: That's the most weird thing. It seems they fired the dev or scraped the team before they could finish implementing the full set of markdown. :)

Comment: Kids these days, with no collective memory for usenet conventions.  ;^)

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to development on OS X, but -- I've been using the simple-but-it-works [MarkdownLive](https://github.com/rentzsch/markdownlive) for the same purpose. I think I've been using the free version of [MarkdownPad](http://markdownpad.com/download.html) on Windows, although I keep meaning to check out the MD functionality in [WriteMonkey](http://writemonkey.com/). Going forward, I almost certainly will just be using [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2).

You might check out what [Brett Terpstra](http://brettterpstra.com/) is doing ... doubt he is running Outlook, but it might be a problem he has addressed all the same. I also want to look at this [package of scripts for Marked](http://support.markedapp.com/kb/how-to-tips-and-tricks/marked-bonus-pack-scripts-commands-and-bundles)

Hm. My work email is accessed through Outlook's web UI ... I think I smell a Chrome extension around here somewhere ...